# Scrollable List of Images in Images

Tags: android, image, list, scrollable, concept

I want to make a scrollable list of images on other images. Just like this concept:[image]

My "problems" are that I do not really do much with layouts and that I have to change the images programmatically.
I would just write a class which would handle the scrolling animation and change the position of every image when Action_Move is called, but I am completly sure that there is a better option which is the reason that I ask you now. I hope you can help me. :)

Comment: So you want a list of items and every item is a group of twelve image?

Comment: Use Recyclerview and gridlayout as layoutManager and populate the recyclervView with images.

Comment: @Eselfar kind of. but every item has a background image as well.

Comment: Right now I do not have a layout file at all. I am using a SurfaceView to draw on the canvas.

Comment: Dunno what you want to do at the end, but the easier way to do that is to use a RecyclerView with a list of items. Each item has 12 ImageViews and a background.